# Is there a more pythonic way of passing a queryset to a django modelformset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-forms

I need a form with 25 objects (players of a football team). The user logs, the query fetched the his team's players, and shows them allowing him to choose who to put in the first team, who on the bench, who to leave out.

Now, if a user logs in, and didn't insert his team for the actual fixture, the view will create initial data and will show him the form with the initial data. If he already put the team in, if he wants to edit the line up before the match starts, he sees what have been his last choices, and he'll be able to edit.

When the user access the page, the view queries the database: if the queryset is empty, the initial data are created with `bulk_create`, then I refetch the data creating a queryset which is not going to be empty and I populate the formset with it; if the query returns something, then the queryset will populate the formset.

The structure of my view, simplified, is the following:

```
def view_name(request):


    MyModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel, form = MyModelForm ,formset = BaseBaseMyModelFormSet, extra=0)


    if request.method=='POST':

        formset = MyModelFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        else:

        return render(request,'ins_form.html',{'league':league,'formset':formset})
    else:        
        team=request.user.blablablagetterightteam
        q_set=MyModel.objects.filter(giornata=giornata_attuale, team=team)

        if len(q_set)==0:
            Rosa=team.Rosa()
            MyModel.objects.bulk_create([MyModel(footballer=pl.footballer, giornata=giornata_attuale, team=team) for pl in Rosa])

            q_set=MyModel.objects.filter(giornata=giornata_attuale, team=team)

    formset = MyModelFormSet(queryset=q_set)

    return render(request, 'ins_form.html', {'league':league,'formset': formset})
```

Now, I would prefer to not save the query with the `bulk_create`, I just want to save the data when the data is submitted. I tried with initial, passing a list of dictionaries instead of a queryset but I obtain strange behaviour when fetching data which have been already saved.

Any idea?

Comment: use `inlineformset_factory` https://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/

Comment: I don't get how that would solve my problem.